# Are commits from local branches that aren't pushed accessible at the remote?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch

Say I have the following scenario:

- Currently on master, do `git checkout -b test`.
- Make some commits A and B in `test`.
- Go back to master with `git checkout master`.
- Make some commits C and D, then push to the remote master.

If this happens, from a security perspective are commits A and B accessible in any way to someone who views the remote repo? E.g., if they do a `git clone` and then try `git checkout A`, what would be the result?

Comment: No. Pushing is, by definition, the copying of one or more commits to a remote repository. If you don't push `test`, nothing reachable only by `test` gets copied.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, that's what I assumed but wanted to double check.

Comment: @InertialIgnorance if it is resolved remember to close the question :)